# Custom stock status considering the quantity

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, quantity, stock-status

Magento 1.9.2 Problem.
I have the code below to show me custom text depending if a product is out of stock.
The thing i want to do is to get all products in stock and if the quantity is 0 or below to get my custom text

```
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $_product->getData('customstock'); ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Do you have issue with getting your `customstock` data in `$_product->getData('customstock')` or with product quantity calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with this :

```
<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $_product->getCustomstock(); ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**[EDIT]**

Or you can use this code:

```
<?php  $_qty = $_product->getStockItem()->getQty();
if($_qty>0) { ?>

<p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php } else { ?>
 <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $_product->getCustomstock(); ?></span></p>

 <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: @Aruendra
It returns blank page.
I think it must something like 
if qty>0-> in stock
if qty<=0 custom text

Comment: @CostasSaloubardos please check now